# Prove the extension field is a root field of some polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let K be an extension of F such that [K:F] = 2. Prove that K is a root field of some polynomial over F.

$\underline{Pf:}$

Let [K:F] = 2

Let $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + x^2$ be minimal polynomial

Let c be  a root of f(x), so f(c) = 0

Then to find the other factor of $f(x)$ use long division:

$x-c | f(x) = x + (c + a_1)$

remainder: $c(c+a_1) + a_0 = f(c)= 0$?

Then the basis of K over F is { c, -c-$a_1$}

Therefore, K is a root field of $f(x)$ over F.

Is this sufficient proof and/or sound logic?

Comment: You should mention that since the degree is two, some element must have degree two over the base field. Additionally, you ought to show that $c$ and $-c-a_1$ are linearly independent, since (for example) they are not if $a_1=0$.